# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': pos 12: 'child != null': is not true

Tags: dart, flutter

```
    class AddDineinOrderForm extends StatefulWidget {
      final MainModel model;
      AddDineinOrderForm(this.model);
      @override
      State createState() => _AddDineinOrderFormState();
    }

    class _AddDineinOrderFormState extends State<AddDineinOrderForm> {

      final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
      final Map<String, dynamic> _formData = {
        'userName': null,
        'mobileNumber': null,
        'noOfPersons': null
      };

      _onSubmit(model){
        if (_formKey.currentState == null || !_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          return;
        }
        _formKey.currentState.save();
        model.addNewDineInOrder(_formData);
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/add_items');
      }

      Widget _customerNameField(){
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
          child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1.0),
          labelText: 'Customer Name',
        ),
        onSaved: (val){
          _formData['userName'] = val ;
        },
        validator: (val){
          if(val.isEmpty){
            return 'Please enter customer name';
          }
        },
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget _customerNumberField(){
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
          child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone_android),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1.0),
          labelText: 'Customer Mobile Number',
        ),
        onSaved: (val){
          _formData['mobileNumber'] = val ;
        },
        validator: (val){
          if(val.isNotEmpty && val.length != 10){
            return 'Please enter valid mobile number';
          }
        },
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget _buildMemberCount(){
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
          child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_add),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1.0),
          labelText: 'Number of persons on Table',
        ),
        onSaved: (val){
          _formData['noOfPersons'] = int.parse(val) ;
        },
        validator: (val){
          if(val.isEmpty){
            return 'Please enter number persons';
          }
        },
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget _buildAddOrder(context, model){
        return Container(
          child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _onSubmit(model);
        },  
        child: Text('Add Items',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget _buildOrderForm(model){
        return Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          _customerNameField(),
          _customerNumberField(),
          _buildMemberCount(),
          _buildAddOrder(context, model)
        ],
          ),
        );
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return ScopedModelDescendant(
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Add User Info'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: _buildOrderForm(model),
          ),
        );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

The below is the error

```
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4131 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1744 pos 12: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true.
    I/flutter (24195): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 2284 pos 16: '!_dirtyElements[index]._active || _dirtyElements[index]._debugIsInScope(context)': is not true.
```

Comment: What code caused the exception?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  
In the debug console it is showing some error when the page with some textfield is navigated to the next page. And when ever preceeding textfiled is focused I'm getting the below error on device Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3549 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true. –

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  Also this error "Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1744 pos 12: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true."

Comment: No way to give any advice without seeing the code that causes the issue. Try removing as much code as possible so that you have the essential parts left required to reproduce the issue and then post this code an the full error output.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  .,  Please view the post in github where I had posted complete code of the page and error as well.

 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26849

Comment: Please don't post support requests in GitHub. Rather improve the question here so that others are able to debug and diagnose the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187048/discussion-between-kurru-hem-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: GitHub is for Flutter bug reports and feature requests. You can post full code here as well, but "full code" should *always* be the absolute minimum required to reproduce the problem. The more unrelated code it contains the less likely anyone will read it to the end. This does not mean to remove simple code like imports or similar.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
Expanded(
child:Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: _buildOrderForm(model),
  ),
)
```